# Bash/perl function for filtering and formatting `/etc/fstab`

Tags: bash, perl

The following function filters and formats `/etc/fstab` for future use. Comments are in [TomDoc](http://tomdoc.org/) format.

```bash
# Internal: filters and formats lines in /etc/fstab using Perl.
# When run it: removes comments, splits fstab columns (listed below) into the $fstab array.
# fstab columns: <file system> <mount point> <type>  <options> <dump>  <pass>
# The $fstab array can then be used to filter and format the output as shown in the below example.
# 
# $1 - filter (default: '1').
# $2 - format (default: 'print $_').
#
# Returns lines from /etc/fstab filtered using the filter from $1, and formatted using format from $2
#
# Examples
# 
#  fstab_list '$fstab[0]=~/UUID/' 'print $fstab[0], " at ", $fstab[1]'
#  # UUID=149294d6-cc19-441f-bfd1-ee21ed843af1 at /
#  # UUID=4CDC-4211 at /boot/efi
# 
fstab_list(){
  local filters="${1:-'1'}" # maybe make this always filter for glusterchroot
  local format="${2:-'print $_'}"
  perl -wnl -e "/^[^#]+/ or next; @fstab=split(/\s+/, $&); ${filters} and ${format};" /etc/fstab
}
```

Comment: I rolled back the last edit. After receiving an answer the code should not be changed anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Answer (score 4):

Wow, there's a libc function that perl doesn't offer access to!

[getmntent](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html):

> ... reads the next line of the filesystem description file from stream and returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken out fields

Not a very fancy function, we can readily re-implement it, OK.

---

Looks good.
I don't really recommend any changes.
But here are my musings.

---

```
# fstab columns: <file system> <mount point> <type>  <options> <dump>  <pass>
```

Thank you for the reminder, that's helpful.
Now I have it all on one screen in front of me,
without flipping back and forth to a man page.

```
# $1 - filter (default: '1').
```

I confess that I misread this the first time.
We're in a bash context, and I initially didn't understand
that I was reading an idiomatic perl expression for True.
IDK, maybe name it `filter_predicate`?
Maybe point out that we're using perl?
No biggie, it becomes obvious soon enough.

```
# $2 - format (default: 'print $_').
```

Sorry, I tend to think of "format" in terms of `sprintf()`, distinct from I/O.
Consider making it `'$_'` and
then your scaffolding *always* prints the formatted string?

```
#  fstab_list '$fstab[0]=~/UUID/' 'print $fstab[0], " at ", $fstab[1]'
```

Warning, creeping featurism! Quick, skip to next section.

Your script offers a pretty thin wrapper.
Consider making it fatter,
by replacing inconvenient cryptic integer indexes
with `mntent` names of {fsname, dir, type, opts, freq, passno}.
Then we can access fstab at a higher level of abstraction.

---

```
  local format="${2:-'print $_'}"
```

Consider adding:

```
  local fstab="${3:-'/etc/fstab'}"
```

and passing that along to perl.

Why?
To make it possible for a maintenance engineer
to write automated test cases,
feeding in some "hard to parse" frozen fstab text.

I like the quoting and the perl parsing, it all looks good.
I imagine this runs cleanly through `shellcheck` -- kudos.

---

```
  perl -wnl -e ...
```

Consider tacking on `-Mstrict`, just in case.
Couldn't hurt, it's a good habit.

---

This code appears to achieve its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Re "*Thank you for the reminder, that's helpful.*", Also, it gives something to reference if the format changes (e.g. if you port the script to a different system that has different columns).